# Happy 100th day!

Tags: discussion

Happy 100th day of existence on StackExchange!  I'll brink the cake, if you bring the beverages!

But, seriously, I wanted to thank all of you who have worked hard to answer nearly every question and form this site into what it is.  I wish we were getting a few more questions than we are, but the answers are quick and of high quality.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks :) I'm very please we've got so far.